# Calculate the coordinates of a triangular prism given the coordinates of a triangle and length in 3d space

Tags: geometry

Given any three coordinates in 3d space that make up a triangle (say A, D and E) and length n (the distance between A and B), how can I calculate the coordinates of B, C and F.

[image]

I assume I take the surface normal and use it to transform each coordinate, but I am not sure what the calculation is.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Find $\vec{AD}, \vec{AE}$ and do a cross product to find the normal vector, normalize it to get unit normal and then multiply by length $|AB|$. Adding this to the position vectors $A, D, E \,$ will give you coordinates of $B, C, F$ but your normal vector can be in either direction of the plane that $\triangle ADE$ is in. So you will have two possible coordinates unless you have additional constraints given.

Comment: I will be using a direction (clockwise) around coordinates stored in an array.

Comment: To get the exact view as shown in the diagram, you need to take $\vec{AD} \times \vec {AE}$ when following Math Lover's instructions. If you use $\vec{AE} \times \vec {AD}$ instead, you'll end up with $\triangle BCF$ on the other side of $\triangle ADE$ from what is shown.

Comment: Sorted. Works a treat. Thanks.

Comment: Your drawing seems ok but the writing is missing.